# VS/MSBUILD: Copy output files of sub-project without adding reference to exe

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, project-reference

I have a solution wich consists of main application `MainProject` and several plugin projects `Plugin1`, `Plugin2` etc. Each of them is build in a separate project within Visual Studio.

For building the soution, I want all files of the plugins to be copied into the main application's output directory. But I don't want `MainProject.exe` to contain explicit references to the plugin dlls (they are loaded dynamically). Therefore defining project references for `MainProject`doesn't work.

I could use a post-build-step copying the files "manually" (as described in [C# - Copy dlls to the exe output directory when using dependency injection with no references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606670/c-sharp-copy-dlls-to-the-exe-output-directory-when-using-dependency-injection)), but since there might be multiple files for each plugin and they also change from time to time this solution is rather tedious to maintain (especially since I do have different build configurations, each of them producing different files). Also I would like to easily select, which plugins should be copied for a certain build.

What would be the best way, possibly involving custom MSBuild configuration changes, to do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a good way to do this? I think if someone wrote a nice plugin for VS2012 and a custom MSBuild step to go along with it, this would be very pragmatic and awesome!

Answer (score 0):

See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
When invoking MSBuild on the main project, if you could pass something on the lines of:

```
msbuild /p:CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets=[your custom msbuild file];PluginList=PathToPlugin1.csproj,PathToPlugin2.csproj
```

In your custom msbuild file, a target such as GatherInfo will get you the paths to output files of each plugin project. See this question for a sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23346782/how-to-identify-files-needed-to-build-a-wix-project